# How can I loop over element ids in an array and assign them to variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to refactor my window.onload function so as to avoid redundancy. I'd like to loop over the elements I'm assigning to global variables, using their ids. Initially, I was able to assign onclick functions with a loop, but now I'm not able to reproduce this in a fiddle. But the main issue is simply trying to do this (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sea0tpm/6/)):

```
var gragh, gorgh;
var ids = ["gragh", "gorgh"];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    ids[i] = document.getElementById(ids[i]);  
    // TypeError: document.getElementById(ids[i]).onclick = doStuff;
}
//console.log(gragh);  undefined
```

This is supposed to assign the variables gragh and gorgh to p elements which have the same ids. Within the loop, ids[i] seems to refer to the p elements. After the loop, however, these variables are undefined. This also doesn't work when looping through an array with these variables not surrounded by quotes. I've even tried using eval(), with mixed results. So my question is, how can I get this to work? And also, why doesn't this work? If ids = [gragh, gorgh] (without the quotes), what do these variables within the array refer to?

Comment: Well, I should say that neither of the below methods work for assigning values to global variables outside of window.onload. Any more ideas? I was also looking for more general explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reassign it in your loop, try using a new array to populate. Think of it as a reference - you're modifying it while looping.

```
var gragh, gorgh;
var ids = ["gragh", "gorgh"];
var newSet = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    newSet[i] = document.getElementById(ids[i]);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop will finish it's looping much before this `onclick` executes.So at that time the value of `i` will be the upper limit of the loop.

A work around of this a `closure`

```
var gragh;
var ids = ["gragh", "gorgh"];
for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    (function(i){ // creating closure
  console.log(i)
    document.getElementById(ids[i]).onclick = doStuff
})(i) // passing value of i
}

document.getElementById("gragh").innerHTML = "ids[0]: " + ids[0] + ", ids[1]: " + ids[1]

function doStuff() {
  document.getElementById("gorgh").innerHTML = "ids[0]: " + ids[0] + ",ids[1]: " + ids[1] + ", var gragh: " + gragh;
}
```

`gragh` is undefined since you haveonly declared it but never initialized it

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9sea0tpm/7/)

Comment: Actually, the onclick events work. In my program, I have buttons initialized thusly in window.onload: var buttons = ["start", "stop", "pause", "speed"];
      for (var button of buttons) { document.getElementById(button).onclick = eval(button); } These are not global variables, though.